# Не работает филтрация вариативных товаров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

имеется интернет магазин на Woocommerce, добавлены вариативные товары (по объему памяти, по цвету, по цене)
https://apphone.ru/iphone/
Хочу настроить фильтр по цене, цвету, объему памяти, но все плагины фильтрации некорректно работают, не сортируют товары по одному цвету, по конкретному диапазону цен и тд
как можно решить проблему подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4):

Данный плагин работает отлично: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/premmerce-woocommerce-product-filter/

Comment: дело в том, что мне например нужно указать цену минимальную в категории, от 5000 до 5000 руб например и товары пишет что не найдены

Comment: данный плагин работает корректно с вариативными ценами

Comment: хочу отсортировать товар по цвету (в карточке товара при выборе цвета, изображение меняется), premmerce и другие фильтры не работают

Comment: он работает на дефолтном шаблоне вукоммерса. Если вы в своей теме переопределили шаблоны вука, не ожидайте найти готовое решение